# Strange twisted bone with Copy Rotation

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I'm trying to use the Copy Rotation Constraint to let an armature copy another armature. The problem is, that the copied bone somehow is turned like 360 degrees around the x axis. What could I do to solve this problem?

Without the constraint, it looks like this:

[image]

After adding the constraint, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I fixed your images, please next time use the question editor tools to insert images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do. First would be to adjust the "Roll" of bones in edit mode, then they will have the same starting rotation. You can also restrict rotation on the axis of weird twisting or in Copy Rotation Constraint properties set copy only to those axis that work properly, or if the rotation of bones on the twisting axis is exactly opposite, select Invert in Copy Rotation Constraint properties for this axis, but if you want to have easy life with the rig, use the first option.